# "more" link in footer is hardly viewable

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

In the footer, the **more** link is hardly view-able due to the free handed image in the background, when select the **Technology** sites.

Screenshot for reference:

[image: more link]

Comment: Thanks for reporting that! I need to make some adjustments to that background image and will definitely do! Expect it in, hopefully, 1 week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks again for reporting this issue.

I've fixed that by changing background position for this image. It (doodle) will now be attached to right edge of the screen and disappear for smaller screen resolutions.

Fix is now waiting in repo for next build - should be live in couple hours.

Comment: The issue has been fixed in `rev 2017.8.24.26840`